# Convert Datatable's date-type column to short date on output - VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, datatable

Experts, please help...

I have a datatable where I load in data from a SQL Server database with tens of thousands of records and I have a procedure which outputs the entire datatable to a delimited text file.

My procedure to do so has code along the following lines:

```
For Each dtRow As DataRow In dtToWrite.Rows
     File.WriteLine(String.Join(strDelimitter, dtRow.ItemArray.Select(Function(Field) Field.ToString)))
Next
```

Basically creating a delimited string from each datarow from my datatable using the string.join function.

Now, my problem is that I am pulling in Date values from SQL Server and so the final output has, for the date columns, values that look like:

**"9/30/2012  12:00:00 AM"**

Whereas I only want it to show:

**"9/30/2012"**

What is the best way to get my data to output ONLY the date portion from the datatable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your SQL Query, you could convert the DateTime to a preformatted string.  Like this:

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 101)
```

For more date formats, check out the [MSDN list of formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: That is AWESOME - I would still like to know if I could do it in code, but this definitely worked!!!

Answer (score 1):

You could simply not return the time part of the Date in your query like `tgolisch` states or  just use `.Split()` on the string.

```
Dim dateOnly As String = yourString.Split(" ")(0);
```

Comment: ... the challenge with this is that the way i'm writing to the text file doesn't really go field-by-field... I know I could do something with an if statement in my Select(Function(Field) Field.ToString), but i was hoping for a neater way...

Answer (score 1):

```
File.WriteLine(String.Join(strDelimitter, dtRow.ItemArray.Select(Function(Field) DateTime.Parse(Field.ToString).ToShortDateString())))
```

Convert the value to a DateTime, then call its .ToShortDateString() method.  This will be culture dependent.

Comment: ... This assumes that all the fields are Date fields... I know i could put in an IF clause, but I was hoping for a better way...